# SyntaxHighlighter is not defined

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to integrate this [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/installation.html) to my website.
I included all files exactly how in the example, but it does not work.

When I take a look at the web concole it says

> ReferenceError: SyntaxHighlighter is not defined @ shBrushPhp.js:81

*shBrushPhp.js* is part of the files i had to include and I wounder why it does not work. Any ideas?

It would also help if you could say me where SyntaxHighlighter is normally defined.

The line where the error occurrs:

```
Brush.prototype = new SyntaxHighlighter.Highlighter();
```

Comment: Post the code here too

Comment: R u include syntaxhighter js above the shBrushPHP.js

Comment: Yes I do, all files are correctly included.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page that this is happening on? Clearly things are not 'correctly' included, since it's not working; being able to see the page in question will let us help you figure out the problem here.

Comment: @Dancrumb He should include code here to make this question a useful one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 4):

It's a pity, that the interrogator didnt follow the answers to his questions. So the question is still open and we have wether a link nor a code snippet.

At least i had the same error ("SyntaxHighlighter is not defined") and i solved it with bringing my script-tags into the correct order. So make sure you import both javascript files (shCore.js and shBrushJScript.js) in the right order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/shBrushJScript.js"></script>
```

You can see that in the SyntaxHighlighter website you have linked to.

The SyntaxHighlighter object is initialized when running through the shBrushJScript.js. So at this point the SyntaxHightlighter - defined in shCore.js - have to be known. If the SyntagHighlighter is announced later in the code, shBrushJScript does not know it.

Comment: My problem turned out to be referencing the files from the author's host location (http) from my blogger blog (https).  So I had to find somewhere to host them from via https.